# Is the javascript Google Search API deprecated?

Tags: javascript, google-search-api

I am trying to use google search API. 
but https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/ says it is deprecated.
Is there a newer project for the same?
My requirement is to automate google search in a web page.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this is the alternative: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099663/alternative-to-the-deprecated-google-rest-web-search-api?rq=1

Comment: Great! Glad you found the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The same page also says you to move to https://developers.google.com/custom-search/