# How to export search results (JSON, XML, or other) using R?

Tags: json, r

I want to download results from search a engine in JSON, XML or other format using R but don't know where to start. Think of a general search for example of a company name and some other key words, like "bhp billiton iron ore production".

- Google Search API is deprecated
- I seems to be to difficult to "convert" my search phrases to Yahoo's YQL
- Not sure that Yahoo BOSS would do the job (would it?)

I'm just looking for a simple tool to feed with search phrases and receive the results in a reasonable format. It is also necessary to be able to do a bit more advanced search like using AND/OR, 'within n words', doing it web and or news search, etc.

Can you give me any advice what to use?

Comment: For R scraping , Take a look at some packages like `XML` , `rvest` ( You should have some **xpath** skills) ,`rjson` to format your json results. Otherwise If you have some python skills , better to use something like `scrapy` ( It is the work-horse) for scraping.

Comment: This question will be rather closed because it asking for a tool and not a real question.

Comment: This is a Q&A site. Asking for tools / general information is not appropriate.  Regardless, [THIS](http://gastonsanchez.com/work/webdata/) is an excellent resource.

Comment: Thank you for the help and sorry that it is so general, newbie mistake. 
Most links are dead but gives an idea where to look.
I found a similar thread here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099663/)